# How can await mySql result before return NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I am developing an application in NodeJS that queries two different MySQL databases, I have a problem with the asynchronous behavior of the language.

What happens is I make a query to the database, but the application continues before the database returns the response of the query.

How can I place an await or make the function return when the query has finished?

for the database connection I am using the mysql package

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection_dblink = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'carritos_lead_ac_test'
});

connection_dblink.connect(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('conexion dblink --> N O T  O K <-- ');
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log('conexion dblink OK');
    }
})
```

It works correctly, it brings the data but after the return.

The structure of the function that is giving the problem

```
async function getContact(contact) {
    let responseGetContactFunc = connection_dblink.query(`SELECT * FROM contacto WHERE rut = "${contact.rut}";`,  function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR");
            throw err;
        } else {
            return result[0];
            
        }
    });
    console.log(responseGetContactFunc._ended);
}
```

**return result[0];** it is the value that I need to wait for before continuing with the execution of the rest of the application

**console.log(responseGetContactFunc._ended);** returns false because logically the query has not finished yet.

Comment: Use the promise version of the mysql connector. Then you can use `await connection_dblink.query(...)`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql this ?

Comment: yes, I think that's it

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue by promisifying the query connection using utils. So the **connection has to be modified** as bellow.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
const util = require("util"); // used to promisify

var connection_dblink = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "carritos_lead_ac_test",
});

connection_dblink.connect(function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("conexion dblink --> N O T  O K <-- ");
    throw error;
  } else {
    console.log("conexion dblink OK");
  }
});

var modified_connection_dblink = util.promisify(connection_dblink.query).bind(connection_dblink);
```

Then it can be used as bellows.

```
async function getContact(contact) {
  try{
      let responseGetContactFunc = await modified.connection_dblink(`SELECT * FROM contacto WHERE rut = "${contact.rut}";`)
      return responseGetContactFunc[0];
    }
    catch(e){
        return e;
    }
 }
```

I use try catch blocks to handle errors. Hope it fixes your issue.